# C++ Invalid arguments using a function from class included from different file

Tags: c++, class

I have the following decleration in file Order.h (Holdng class Order) :

```
void removeFromAlbum(int barcode);
```

and the following Implementation line:

```
void Order::removeFromAlbum(int barcode)
```

But, when im trying to call the function with a different file, Store.cpp (Order.h was included) with the following line :

```
order.removeFromAlbum(barcode);
```

I get the following error from eclipse :

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void removeFromAlbum(int)
'
```

Eclipse is well defined.
Any suggestions ?

Edit :
This is the function when all the magic happens :

```
void Store::removeFromOrder(int ordNum, int barcode)
```

barcode is an int.

Comment: What type is barcode?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error code that you get? The types of the arguments is not shown...

Comment: Do you get an error when compiling, or is this only reported by the IDE while editing?

Comment: Only in the IDE, I cant compile it for now because I must compile it on a different server (of my universoty) which isnt available atm.

Comment: Summarizing code that you can't get to compile is **never** a good idea. If you understood it well enough to summarize it accurately you'd understand it well enough to see what's wrong. At the very least, include a trimmed version of `Order` that shows the declaration of the member function that's being called and include the call that's failing. And make sure that the code is complete enough to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Before the OP's edit, it was impossible to tell if `barcode` was an integer. This answer may, therefore, be invalid:

It looks like you're trying to call the function `removeFromAlbum()` with a type that isn't an `int`. Ensure that `barcode` is actually cast as an `int`.